# Reverse jQuery iosslider direction

Tags: jquery, slider, right-to-left

I am a beginner and trying to convert iosslider support RTL(right to left) and I have one problem. in this code in 
jquery.iosslider.min.js

how can Reverse this code

```
 setSliderOffset: function(e, d) {
 ca && !Z && !$ ? a(e).css({
 webkitTransform: "matrix(1,0,0,1," + d + ",0)",
 MozTransform: "matrix(1,0,0,1," + d + ",0)",
 transform: "matrix(1,0,0,1," + d + ",0)"
 }) : a(e).css({
 left: d + "px"
```

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want iosslider work correctly in rtl languages you have to add this code

```
direction: "ltr",
```

after any

```
 position: "relative",
```

also after

```
stageCSS: {
```

in jquery.iosslider.min.js and jquery.iosslider.js files